# PHP Laravel read csv

Tags: php, laravel, csv, maatwebsite-excel

I have a CSV file where the data is in landscape orientation.ex:

```
name, test name
age, 20
gender,Male
```

where the first column is the headers and the second the data, i tried using `laravel maatwebsite/Excel` and the response after reading the file, the first row is taken as the headers. (`name` and `test name`).

is there any method to read this type of CSV files in laravel using maatwebsite/Excel

Comment: That's just a badly formed csv.  Almost all csv specs define records per line and fields of that record separated by a delimiter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this function

```
public function readCSV($csvFile, $delimiter = ',')
{
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while ($csvRow = fgetcsv($file_handle, null, $delimiter)) {
        $line_of_text[] = $csvRow;
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}
$csvFileName = "test.csv";
$csvFile = public_path('csv/' . $csvFileName);
$this->readCSV($csvFile,array('delimiter' => ','))
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need an entire library. PHP has a built-in function http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: This is the more general and isolated answer: no third party packages, no functions, just direct a PHP function.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter for such small CSVs, but try to demand of those who give you CSVs to have them properly formatted, and not transposed or use [online solutions](https://www.convertcsv.com/transpose-csv.htm) to do so yourself. Here's the solution, but it stores the entire array in memory, even though the package in the first example is specifically made to avoid that.

#### With composer

You may use Spatie's [`simple-excel`](https://github.com/spatie/simple-excel) like so:

```php
$csv = __DIR__ . '/data.csv';
$data = [];
SimpleExcelReader::create($csv)
    // ->useDelimiter(';') // Optional
    ->noHeaderRow() // Optional
    ->getRows()
    ->each(function(array $row) use (&$data) {
        $length = count($row);
        for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $data[$i - 1] ??= [];
            $data[$i - 1][$row[0]] = $row[$i];
        }
});
```

<del>I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/spatie/simple-excel/issues/98) for your use-case.</del> *(Issue was closed, due to the solution not being memory efficient)*

#### Without composer

As said by "online Thomas", there's a native PHP function for that, and I find it easiest to use it, in general, like so:

```
$csv = __DIR__ . '/data.csv';
$data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csv));
```

*Caveat: does not produce the desired results, if fields contain linebreaks*

Use closure in your case, or if you need a delimiter other than ',', etc.:

```
$csv = __DIR__ . '/data.csv';
$data = [];
array_map(function ($line) {
    $row = str_getcsv($line);
    $length = count($row);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) use (&$data) {
       $data[$i - 1] ??= [];
       $data[$i - 1][$row[0]] = $row[$i];
    }
}, file($csv));
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2022 readers: what I am using right now is: https://github.com/spatie/simple-excel

work like a charm with no memory usage due to LazyCollections